# Substitute for flexDirection : 'row'

Tags: javascript, react-native

My scrollview is not working if it's child's style is set flexDirection : 'row', so is there any alternative method to align the child components in a row?

Comment: please share code and demo

Comment: there is always a way but you need to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll view have a prop named `horizontal` {Boolean}, by default it is false which makes scroll view scroll in vertical direction set it to true.

When true, the scroll view's children are arranged horizontally in a row instead of vertically in a column. The default value is false.